# Check if a dictionary exists in list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list which contains some dicts:

```
dict1 = {
'key1': 'value1',
'key2': 'value2',
}

dict2 = {
'key1': 'value3',
'key2': 'value4',
}

list = [dict1, dict2]
```

I am using this to check if dict exists in list or not, for example I changed `dict1` to this

```
dict1 = {
'key1': 'something',
'key2': 'value2',
}
```

Now, checking for `dict1`

```
if dict1 in list:
    print('Exists')
else:
    print('Not exists')
```

It must return `'Not exists'`, but it did not.

Comment: Your example works as intended for me... On a side note, don't name your variable `list`, since it's a name of a built-in function

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do.  Python is checking each item in the list against the item in your comparison using the equality operators as defined by their types.  If they are equivalent then the *in* (membership) operator will evaluate to *True* otherwise it will evaluate to *False*.  You're claiming that this is not what's happening.  I suggest you retrace your steps and confirm what you're seeing.

Comment: Someting wrong in my code, thanks @Jim

Comment: @JimDennis The behavior the OP describes is correct because they create a *new* `dict` object

Comment: thanks @Railslide anyway.

Comment: @Chris_rands Actually he claimed that it was not returning what he expected (False).  But after retracing his steps at my suggestion he got it.

It actually the *id()* values of these dictionaries don't matter.  The *in* operator on the list will check equality across the board.  I've just tested this by creating two dictionaries with identical literal definitions and they both return *True* for being *in* my list.  The difference is that modifying *dict1* will maintain the equality because only a reference to it is stored in the list (they references refer to the same object).

Comment: @JimDennis Completely agree with that Jim, good summary

Comment: @Chris_Rands if I run the example in the shell I get "Not exists", which is what the OP expected but somehow didn't get (or at least that's how I interpreted the question)

Comment: @Railslide Indeed, I interpreted the question differently (probably wrongly) but I think we are all on the same page now thanks

Comment: I'm very confused, can someone explain how running this code snippet ended up giving the OP `Exists`? I am trying to figure out if I am safe to use this `in` operator or whether I should use something custom...

Answer (score 18):

> Note `list` is a built-in function, use different name, such as `my_list`

It returns `False` as shown below:

```
>>> dict1
{'key2': 'value2', 'key1': 'value1'}
>>> my_list = [dict1, dict2]
>>> dict1 in my_list
True
>>> dict1 = {
... 'key1': 'something',
... 'key2': 'value2',
... }
>>> dict1 in my_list
False
```

Comment: You reassign the dict variable here. So the original object `dict1` is not equal the new object `dict1`. That is why it is not in the list. If you change it like `dict1['key1'] = "other"` the check would be `True`!

Answer (score 8):

The behavior you describe is correct because you create a new `dict` when you re-assign it to `dict1` rather than *modifying* the existing `dict`, you can see this by tracking the identity of `dict1`:

```
>>> dict1 = {
... 'key1': 'value1',
... 'key2': 'value2',
... }
>>> 
>>> dict2 = {
... 'key1': 'value3',
... 'key2': 'value4',
... }
>>> 
>>> list = [dict1, dict2]
>>> dict1 in list
True
>>> id(dict1)
140141510806024
>>> dict1['newkey'] = 'value' # modify the dict
>>> id(dict1)
140141510806024 # the id has not changed
>>> dict1 in list
True
>>> dict1 = {
... 'key1': 'something',
... 'key2': 'value2',
... }
>>> id(dict1)
140141510059144 # the id has changed
>>> dict1 in list
False
```

Note don't use the variable name `list` because it shadows the in-built `list()`.